# What is the zooming bounds of google maps in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, mobile, google-maps-markers

I need the max zoom for move camera function on google maps map view.
I use 24f for zooming but it isn't enought for the project.

```
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinates, 24f));
```

Does anyone have any solution.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Map Api for Androids](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/views) says that the range of zoom levels permitted by the map depends on a number of factors including location, map type and screen size. To get the max zoom level use [getMaxZoomLevel()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#public-float-getmaxzoomlevel);